# Rest API real time Tricky Question- Need Answer

Tags: security, authentication, postman, rest

I was recently interviewed by a MNC technical panel and they asked me different questions related to RestAPI , i was able to answer all but below 2 questions though i answered but not sure if those are correct answers. Can somebody answer my queries with real time examples

1) How can i secure my Rest API when somebody send request from Postman.The user provides all the correct information in the header like session id, Token etc.
My answer was: The users token sent in the header of the request should be associated with the successfully authenticated user info then only the user will be granted access  if the Request either comes from Postman or application calls these API.(The panel said no to my answer)

2) How can i handle concurrency in Rest API Means if multiple users are trying to access the API at the same given time (For e.g multiple post request are coming to update data in a table) how will you make sure one request is served at one time and accordingly the values are updated as requested by different user request.
2) My answer was: In Entitiy framework we have a class called DbUpdateConcurrencyException, This class takes of handling concurrency and serves one request is served at a time. 
I am not sure about my both the above answers and i did not find any specific answer on Googling also.

Your expert help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) It is not possible, requests from Postman or any other client or proxy (Burp, ZAP, etc) are indistinguishable from browser requests, if the user has appropriate credentials (like for example can observe and copy normal requests). It is not possible to authenticate the client application, only the client user.

2) It would be really bad if a web application could only serve one client at a time. Think of large traffic like Facebook. :)  In many (maybe most?) stacks, each request gets its own thread (or similar) to run, and that finishes when the request-response ends. These threads are not supposed to directly communicate with each other while running. Data consistency is a requirement of the persistence technology, ie. if you are using a database for example, it must guarantee that database queries are run one after the other. Note that if an application runs multiple queries, database transactions or locks need to be used on the database level to maintain consistency. But this is not at all about client requests, it's about how you use your persistence technology to achieve consistent data. With traditional RDBMS it's mostly easy, with other persistence technologies (like for example using plaintext files for storage) it's much harder, because file operations typically don't support a facility similar to transactions (but they do support locks, which you have to manage manually).

Comment: Completely Agreed, But i want to know what needs to be done to handle both these scenarios.
1) Securing API when called from Postman
2) How to handle concurrency in API when multiple user tries to access same API.

Comment: @Pinnu I think I answered just that, it makes no sense (and is not possible) to secure "against" Postman, and concurrency in calls to the api is managed by the stack or framework via threads or similar facility. I don't think there is further answer here, that's how it works.